# Which shape optimize the perimeter for a given area?

Tags: optimization, area

I was wondering what is shape that maximize the perimeter for a given area?

In fact I would like to know what would be the most optimized perimeter that I can include in a rectangle. See image below.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: A maximum cannot be attained. For every $n$ there will be a way to get a perimeter that exceeds $n$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you :)

Comment: You need an additional constraint to maximize a perimeter, otherwise as drhab mentions, the maximum is unbounded.

Comment: An example for an infinte perimeter for a given area is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

Comment: You can also take a rectangle of the given area, and stretch it, which makes it thinner...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guessed it had a link with fractals. What if I had a "resolution" limit i.e if I say that my "pencil trace" has a finite width?

Comment: See daw's rectangle...

Comment: In fact I would like to know wich situation is the best between these two if I have a finite pencil width?

[URL=http://imageshack.com/f/hj6m0SUWp][IMG]http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/631/6m0SUW.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: If you want to modify your question, use the [edit] button, this is not what comments are for.

Comment: Sorry, I did change the question and I've added the picture inside.

Comment: You might have to formalize the meaning of "pencil trace width". My gut feeling is that such a "comb" that you already sketched there *might* be optimal, but would also consider some spiral shape. A formal proof of the optimality may be a bit tricky (and would depend on the aforementioned meaning of "pencil trace width": Are you able to draw a *corner* at all, or will the corners always be sligtly "curved"?...etc)

Comment: Sorry it' an artefact of my drawing software. Let's say that we have only right angles. Sorry the pencil trace width it's just a "feeling" about what I'm looking for :). If for example I enlarge the linewidth of the comb (right case on the image) they will merge and the perimeter will decrease. Now if I reduce it I can make two (or more) crenels from one. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: My feeling is that the result will be also a fractal but the order will be limited by the ratio of the rectangle area divided by the line width. But I'm physicist :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you enclose an area equal to $1/3$ of the area of the rectangle. Divide one edge of the rectangle into $n$ equal segments. On each small segment construct an isosceles triangle with height $2/3$ of the width of the rectangle. The total areas of these triangles is $n \times \frac{2/3 \times \ell \times L/n}{2} = 1/3 \ell \times L$.

The sum of the perimeters of these triangles is larger than the sum of the heights which is $n\times \ell \times 2/3$. This quantity is unbounded as $n$ increases. Therefore, there is no configuration which maximizes the perimeter given the enclosed area.